# Dropdown selection resets text field onchange="this.form.submit();"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created a form with multiple sections. Every time I select an answer from the dropdown in a section, the page clears/refreshes data that has already been entered from a different section. The reason I am using the "onchange" event is to display a calculation at the bottom before submitting the form.

Section B:

```html
<label class="sr-only" for="answerone"></label>
    <select id="answerOne" name="answerone" onchange="this.form.submit();"      class="form-control">
    <option value="0" <?php if(isset($_GET['answertwo']) && $_GET['answertwo']=="0") echo "selected"?>>Select One</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_GET['answertwo']) && $_GET['answertwo']=="1") echo "selected"?> >No</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_GET['answertwo']) && $_GET['answertwo']=="2") echo "selected"?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_GET['answertwo']) && $_GET['answertwo']=="3") echo "selected"?>>NA</option>
</select>
```

Section E:

```html
<php ? 
  $totalscore=array($_GET['answerone'],$_GET['answertwo'], $_GET['answerthree']);
                  echo array_sum($totalscore) . "%";

?>
```

Maybe JavaScript or ajax using php could work. I tried using, but I did not know how to store the JavaScript variable to a php variable. I have about 10 questions.

Answer (score 0):

The default method for `<form>` is to POST, thus your other pieces of data are in the `$_POST` variable. Not having seen what your `<form>` tag looks like, it's hard to tell if that is the problem.

It sounds like what you want is to not submit the form every time, but approach it using AJAX. For example, on any particular `<input/>` tag, wire up an event to save data somewhere and display the new data into your calculation.

Comment: I created a dynamic dropdown using the GET method:

Comment: Example: Section 1<form action="" method="get" class="form-inline" id="userid">.....</form>

Comment: Section 2 starts with  <form action="" method="get">.....</form>. All sections are bundled in Section 2. Section B is where everything reset. there are 3 sections in B. I hope this makes sense. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side code (ie. JavaScript) has a different lifetime than server-side code, and that seems to be causing confusion here. It sounds like what's happening is:

1. The user selects a value *client-side*
2. Your JavaScript submits the form, forcing a new page to load
3. Either your form didn't tell the server the value the user selected in #1, or it didn't use it when it re-sent the page
4. As a result you wind up on the page with your selection lost

The solution is either:

- fix your client-side code to send the select's value (which it should already be doing unless you added code to prevent it)
- fix your server-side code to save that value somewhere (eg. in the session or in the database)
- fix your server-side code to use that saved value to mark the appropriate "option" element as "selected" when it returns the page

The exact fix will of course depend on what your actual problem is.